# Replace NA with value from another df by date and city

Tags: r, replace, na

I have two date.frame of the following form with different dimensions. I want to replace the NA values in `df1$NO2`  with the `NO2` value from `df2` by `city` and `date`.
`df1`

```
     city      date       NO2     province 
#1  nanjing   2018-1-1    15      jiangsu
#2  nanjing   2018-1-2    NA      jiangsu 
#3  guangzhou 2018-1-1    NA      guangdong
#4  guangzhou 2018-1-2    NA      guangdong
#5  dongguan  2018-1-1    16      guangdong
     ...       ...       ...       ....
```

`df2`

```
     city      date       NO2           
#1  nanjing   2018-1-2    11.2      
#2  guangzhou 2018-1-1    15.5      
#3  guangzhou 2018-1-2    12.1      
     ...       ...       ...
```

My desired output would be:

`Desired output`

```
    city      date       NO2     province 
#1  nanjing   2018-1-1    15      jiangsu
#2  nanjing   2018-1-2    11.2    jiangsu 
#3  guangzhou 2018-1-1    15.5    guangdong
#4  guangzhou 2018-1-2    12.1    guangdong
#5  dongguan  2018-1-1    16      guangdong
    ...       ...       ...       ....
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We can join the two dataframe and use `coalesce` to select the first non-NA values in two columns.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = c('city', 'date')) %>%
  mutate(NO2 = coalesce(NO2.x, NO2.y)) %>%
  select(names(df1))

#       city     date  NO2  province
#1   nanjing 2018-1-1 15.0   jiangsu
#2   nanjing 2018-1-2 11.2   jiangsu
#3 guangzhou 2018-1-1 15.5 Guangdong
#4 guangzhou 2018-1-2 12.1 Guangdong
#5  dongguan 2018-1-1 16.0 guangdong
```

---

In base R, this can be done via `merge` and `ifelse`

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = c('city', 'date'), 
          all.x = TRUE), NO2 = ifelse(is.na( NO2.x), NO2.y, NO2.x))[names(df1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an update join in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)
df1[is.na(NO2), NO2 := df2[.SD, on=.(city, date), x.NO2]]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot , but I got following error message:    Error in `:=`(NO2, df2[.SD, on = .(city, date), x.NO2]) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").       How should I deal with it

Comment: u have not run the line with `setDT`

Answer (score 0):

Join then mutate using `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by=c('city','date'), suffix=c('','.2')) %>%
  mutate(NO2=as.numeric(NO2),
         NO2=case_when(is.na(NO2) ~ NO2.2,
                       TRUE ~ NO2)) %>%
  select(names(df1))

       city     date  NO2  province
1   nanjing 2018-1-1 15.0   jiangsu
2   nanjing 2018-1-2 11.2   jiangsu
3 guangzhou 2018-1-1 15.5 guangdong
4 guangzhou 2018-1-2 12.1 guangdong
5  dongguan 2018-1-1 16.0 guangdong
```

---

**Data**:

```
df1 <- structure(list(city = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("dongguan", 
"guangzhou", "nanjing"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2018-1-1", "2018-1-2"), class = "factor"), 
    NO2 = c(15L, NA, NA, NA, 16L), province = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("guangdong", "jiangsu"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))

df2 <- structure(list(city = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("guangzhou", 
"nanjing"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2018-1-1", 
"2018-1-2"), class = "factor"), NO2 = c(11.2, 15.5, 12.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Comment: While this works, `case_when` is doing element-wise comparisons, whereas `dplyr::if_else` does vectorized work. `NO2 = if_else(is.na(NO2), NO2.2, NO2)`.

Comment: @r2evans. Are you sure about that? I know that `if_else` is much quicker, and for this example probably better since there's only one condition (`is.na(NO2)`), but I thought `case_when` was also vectorized. And I prefer `case_when` since it is easier to read/debug, and easier to modify if more conditions come along. Good for beginners too. ;)

Comment: You're right ... I don't know where I picked up that assumption. `case_when` appears to be vectorized. Thanks!